# Why is the store to an atomic unique_ptr causing a crash?

Tags: c++, pointers, atomic

The code compiles without issue under VC++2013 (v120) on a i7-4790 Processor (x86-64).

```
int main()
{
    std::atomic<std::unique_ptr<int>> p;
    p.store(std::make_unique<int>(5));
}
```

Once `main()` returns, I get a crash:

> Expression: _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse)

What's going on?

Comment: What compiler and library version?  What CPU architecture?

Comment: @BenVoigt VC++2013 (v120) CPU: i7-4790 Processor (x86-64)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You cannot instantiate a `std::atomic` with a `std::unique_ptr`.  [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic)

> std::atomic may be instantiated with any [TriviallyCopyable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/TriviallyCopyable) type T. std::atomic is neither copyable nor movable.

And a [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) is not TriviallyCopyable

> The class satisfies the requirements of [MoveConstructible](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/MoveConstructible) and [MoveAssignable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/MoveAssignable), but not the requirements of either [CopyConstructible](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/CopyConstructible) or [CopyAssignable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/CopyAssignable).

You could use a [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) that does have [free functions defined to allow you to have atomic stores and loads](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/atomic)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So am I right to assume that the issue here is VC++2013 not doing a static assertion for invalid types `T` for `std::atomic<T>`?

Comment: I do not believe there is any requirement for it to check if `T` is  TriviallyCopyable

Comment: @user2296177 I do not think it is a bug as the standard calls out `T` must be *TriviallyCopyable* so the burden is on you that you give it a correct type.

Comment: That's very true. I still think that a static assert in the implementation would be very helpful in preventing the misuse of the type, even if it's not required by the standard. Thanks for all the help.